# Javascript error: element is null

Tags: javascript, console

Here is all of my code... The inline JavaScript alert is firing off nicely, but the external alert is not. Whenever I reload the page I get a console error log saying "TypeError: tileBlock is null".. Any ideas? I've yet to come across this issue and I'd rather not be forced into writing all of my Javascript event handlers inline. Thanks!

```
#tileBlock {
    position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #0b0b0b;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(photo.jpg);
        border: 20px solid #fff;
        background-size: cover;  
    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {
      #tileBlock {
        border-width: 8px;
      }
    }


<body>
  <div class="wrapper" id="tileBlock" onclick="alert('You clicked (inline)')"></div>
</body>




var tileBlock = document.getElementById('tileBlock');
tileBlock.onclick = function() {
    alert('you clicked(external script)');
}
```

Comment: Your script should be inside <script></script> tags

Comment: It's in an external Javascript file- and anyway I got the same result when I tried putting it in the same file in script tags

Comment: Then you are missing a `window.onload` to run the script after page load

Answer (score 1):

Include jquery library and try this:

```
  $('#tileBlock').onclick(function(){
     alert('you clicked(external script)');
  });
```

Also I have tried your code and it works.(not my jquery)
Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/XcsN/evK3v/

Comment: Thanks so much! I looked at your JsFiddle and it was calling the script on-load. I added the window.onload and that solved it... I did try your JQuery but that doesn't seem any simpler or more effective so I think I'll go with vanilla..

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a window.onload... Thanks everyone for the help!

```
window.onload=function(){
var tileBlock = document.getElementById('tileBlock');
tileBlock.onclick = function() {
    alert('you clicked yes');
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No need window before since it's reserved

```
onload=()=>{
    let elem // etc..
    elem.onclick=()=> // stuff ..
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/cu5b2dch/)